# Jquery animate effect not working at first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I want to animate between swiching divs in a page, when pressing a button ,and i want to animate the swich effect to be fading in and out . But the effect doesn't work when i click on forward arrow , but if i click the back arrow it works.Just the first clicks on forward arrow doesnt work.

Here is my **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs75e68w/)**.

**JS :**

```
contentSlides = $('.article-wrapper');
slidesLeng = contentSlides.length - 1;
index = 0;   
for (i = 0; i <= slidesLeng; i++) {
    $(contentSlides[i]).addClass('slide-' + i);
}



$('.next').on('click', function () {
    if (index != slidesLeng) {
        $(contentSlides[index]).animate({'opacity':'0'},1000).removeClass('active');
        index = index + 1;
        $(contentSlides[index]).animate({ 'opacity': '1'},1000).addClass('active');

    }


});

$('.prev').on('click', function () {
    if (index != 0) {
        $(contentSlides[index]).animate({ 'opacity': '0'},1000).removeClass('active');
        index = index - 1;
        $(contentSlides[index]).animate({ 'opacity': '1'},1000).addClass('active');

    }


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`? Easy as pie!

```
$('.next').on('click', function () {
  if (index != slidesLeng) {
    $(contentSlides[index]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      index++;
      $(contentSlides[index]).fadeIn(1000).addClass('active');
    });
  }
});

$('.prev').on('click', function () {
  if (index != 0) {
    $(contentSlides[index]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      index--;
      $(contentSlides[index]).fadeIn(1000).addClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fm95wc4k/**

Comment: Oh I tried that but in a slightly diffrent way , anyway thank you !